# Error using SelBlocks extension with Selenium server

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, user-extensions.js

I've been recording/writing Selenium html scripts using the SelBlocks extension. Now we're going to use Selenium server to run the tests in different browsers.

I tried getting the javascript from the SelBlock xpi by extracting it and reference that javascript in my selenium server bat file. When I try to run my bat file with referencing the javascript, i got the error "Line: 777 Error: 'XML' is undefined" when I run it in Internet explorer. This happens as the test script is loaded in TestRunner.

When I try to run it in Firefox, TestRunner hangs just prior to running the script.

i'm using Selenium Server 2.1, Firefox 5 and IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Selblocks is only supported for Selenium IDE. See note about "no language translation" here: [Selblocks documentation](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/SelBlocks#SelBlocks-philosophicalnote). Although automated translation would be an interesting area of investigation...

Comment: I wasn't using any programming language on this. I'm only using the HTML scripts recorded from Selenium IDE, then feed those to Selenium RC. I tried to extract the javascript file from SelBlocks, rename it to user-extensions.js and create a batch file command like the following: java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtensions "C:\user-extensions.js" -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://google.com/" "C:\TestSuite.htm" "C:\resultsFirefox.html"

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same thing (Firefox 4.0, Firefox 7.0, selenium-server-2.0.5.jar, SelBlocks 1.3 installed as a firefox plugin).

Since the `-userExtensions` way didn't work for me, I installed SelBlocks 1.3 in the firefox profile I use with `-firefoxProfileTemplate` and `-htmlSuite`.  It looks like selenium server doesn't do anything.

After more than a minute I have:

[image]

so even the selenium elapsed timer doesn't tick, and no line gets executed.

My simple test case is [here](http://pastebin.com/SEa5JqfG).

Looks like I can't use SelBlocks with selenium-server[version].jar for now?

Answer (score -1):

ANNOUNCEMENT: SelBlocks 2.1 now includes support for Selenium Server. Get the extension file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/refactoror/SelBlocks/master/user-extensions.js

Initial browser support is for firefox, googlechrome, and opera.

Comment: obsolete, there (http://refactoror.wikia.com/wiki/Selblocks_Reference) is a notice of serious bug and that Selblocks+Selenium Server is not supported